# Visual Studio - Re-Sharper shortcut broken

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, visual-studio-2013

Uhm I'll try to explain my problem

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and Resharper 8

So I just installed the latest resharper update and I noticed that suddenly I cannot move between my classes/interfaces/variables **names** using the following combination:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

and

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Let's say that I have an interface with the Following Name **`ICommandHandler`**

Assume that the cursor is at the **end** of **`ICommandHandler`**

Before the update when I pressed any of the following combinations the following used to happen:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

The cursor was placed right before the **H** letter

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> again:

The cursor was placed right before the **C** letter

So I was moving exactly where I wanted, to the beginning of each nested word

But after the update when I press the same combination my cursor moves right to the beginning or the end of the word skipping all the inner words which I really hate

Do you know how to fix this?

I already tried to re-apply the resharper shortcut schema several times

Answer (score 1):

I found it....

Resharper - Options - Editor - Editor Behavior - Use CamelHumps